# Reorder the position of the string in the list based on similarity

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a list of string like this -

```
list = ["A","V","C,"D",X","Y","V_RT","D_RT"]
```

I want to reorder the strings with suffix "_RT" right after the parent string(string without the suffix).

For example, the above string should become something like this -

```
list = ["A","V","V_RT","C,"D","D_RT",X","Y"] #notice how the strings with _RT moved after the string without _RT.
```

**My approach-**

Right now I am finding the strings with `_RT`, then searching the index of the parent string without `_RT` and then inserting it there. Finally, deleting the original prefixed string.

The above approach works but I believe there must be some short(one-two liner way) of doing the required which I don't know.

Please help.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention but can't change the order of appearance. After `"A"`, there will be `"V"` then `"V_RT"`, `"C"`, `"D"`, `"D_RT"`, etc. The strings are not necessarily of length 1. The above is just an example.

Comment: Why is this tagged pandas? Are you working with a dataframe?

Comment: @cs95 I am okay to convert the list to a Pandas series or numpy array if that has better flexibility. That is what tagged that.

Comment: @MaxUU Are elements of your list unique, e.g no two `A`s on different places etc.?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Yes.

Comment: @MaxUU And can be element with `_RT` before the element without `_RT`?

Comment: @AndrejKesely You can assume string with `_RT` always appears after the original string(without _RT), but it could be before another original string. For example - A_RT would appear after A, but it could appear before B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach using  *for-loop*

1. Check if *current element + '_RT'* is in original list
2. if `True` add *current element* and *current element + '_RT'* to the new list
3. if `False` and also if substring `'_RT`' is not in *current element* add the element to the new list

**Code:**

```py
l = ["A","V","C","D","X","Y","V_RT","D_RT"]
l2 = []
for x in l:
    if x+'_RT' in l:
        l2+=[x, x+'_RT']
    elif '_RT' not in x:
        l2.append(x)
print(l2)
```

**Output:**

```
['A', 'V', 'V_RT', 'C', 'D', 'D_RT', 'X', 'Y']
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this works and does what I need in a quite concise way.

Answer (score 2):

This does it

```py
list1 = ["A","V","C" ,"D","X","Y","V_RT","D_RT"]
dict1={}
for x in list1:
    dict1[x[0]]=x
list2=[]
for key,value in dict1.items():
    list2.append(key)
    if key!=value:
        list2.append(value)
print(list2)
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this out.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think it also does what I want. Accepting Abhi_J's solution only because it is little compact. +1.